# When does subprocess.Popen return None in Python , sporadically?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

In the following code, I am trying to fork a process for running a command and then capture back the result when the child subprocess has exited.

In the end a loop is run , on a global var, to wait for child process to end so that parent process doesn't exit before child process but overall running of command is non-blocking in a way. The code is working fine 9 out of 10 times but once in a while is giving the error.

Error is in case when it seems `subprocess.Popen` returned `None`. But I am not sure why would that happen randomly.

Can somebody please help in figuring out what is going wrong here ?

**Machine details**

```
[root@1-0-0-9 /]# uname -a
Linux 1-0-0-9 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jan 29 18:37:38 EST 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import subprocess
import signal
import time

flag = False
class Utils(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.child_pid = None
        signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, self.sigchld_handler)

    def sigchld_handler(self, *args):
        print "handling SIGCHLD"
        p = self.child_pid

        stdout_val = p.communicate()[0]
        retcode = p.returncode
        print p.returncode, stdout_val.strip()
        self.child_pid = None
        global flag
        flag = False


    def run_command(self, cmnd, env=None, cwd=None, timeout=0):
        global flag
        flag = True
        cmnd = cmnd.split()
        self.child_pid =subprocess.Popen(cmnd, stdin=None, bufsize=-1, env=env,
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                             close_fds=True, cwd=cwd, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
        print "Invoked child process " , self.child_pid.pid

print "Running command .."
Utils().run_command("ls -lrt")
for i in xrange(10000):
    if not i % 1000:
        print i
print flag
i = 0
while flag:
    i = i + 1
```

**Correct (Desired) Output:**

```
Running command ..
Invoked child process  9703
0
1000
2000
3000
4000
5000
handling SIGCHLD
0 total 52
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root    6 Mar 13  2014 srv
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root    6 Mar 13  2014 mnt
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root    6 Mar 13  2014 media
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root    6 Mar 13  2014 home
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root    7 Jan  9  2016 bin -> usr/bin
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root    9 Jan  9  2016 lib64 -> usr/lib64
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root    7 Jan  9  2016 lib -> usr/lib
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root    8 Jan  9  2016 sbin -> usr/sbin
drwxr-xr-x.  13 root root 4096 Jan  9  2016 usr
drwxr-xr-x.   4 root root   28 Nov 18 16:03 opt
dr-xr-xr-x.   4 root root 4096 Nov 18 16:06 boot
dr-xr-xr-x  178 root root    0 Nov 22 21:53 proc
dr-xr-xr-x   13 root root    0 Nov 22 21:53 sys
drwxr-xr-x.  22 root root 4096 Nov 22 21:53 var
drwxr-xr-x   19 root root 3060 Nov 22 21:53 dev
drwxr-xr-x. 124 root root 8192 Nov 22 21:53 etc
dr-xr-x---.   8 root root 4096 Nov 22 21:53 root
-rw-r--r--    1 root root  573 Nov 22 22:15 a.py
-rw-r--r--    1 root root 1108 Nov 22 22:15 cmnd.py
-rw-r--r--    1 root root 1800 Nov 22 22:15 fork.py
-rw-r--r--    1 root root 1368 Nov 22 22:15 ipc_pipe.py
-rw-r--r--    1 root root  491 Nov 22 22:15 threads.py
drwxr-xr-x   35 root root 1000 Nov 22 22:35 run
drwxrwxrwt.   8 root root 4096 Nov 22 22:35 tmp
6000
7000
8000
9000
False
```

**Error (Failing case):**

```
Running command ..
handling SIGCHLD
handling SIGCHLD
handling SIGCHLD
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cmnd.py", line 37, in <module>
    Utils().run_command("ls -lrt")
  File "cmnd.py", line 33, in run_command
    close_fds=True, cwd=cwd, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1296, in _execute_child
    data = _eintr_retry_call(os.read, errpipe_read, 1048576)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 478, in _eintr_retry_call
    return func(*args)
  File "cmnd.py", line 19, in sigchld_handler
    stdout_val = p.communicate()[0]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'communicate'
```

Comment: Interestingly, "handling SIGCHLD" got printed couple of times. There was only one process forked so why would parent process receive SIGCHLD 3 times ?

Comment: Not sure, but I think you are running into a race condition where you spawn the child process before the assignment of the `Popen` object to `self.child_pid` completes. I would suggest you find a different way to do something when the child finishes, for example waiting on its output, perhaps in a different thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to duplicate the `NoneType` error and it is clearly a race condition. For proof, I imported `traceback` and added `print traceback.print_stack(args[1])` to the signal handler. The stack trace shows that Popen was still waiting on `os.fdopen` when the signal arrived and `self.child_pid` was not yet assigned.

```
Running command ..
handling SIGCHLD
  File "c.py", line 39, in <module>
    Utils().run_command("ls -lrt")
  File "c.py", line 35, in run_command
    close_fds=True, cwd=cwd, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 740, in __init__
    self.stdout = os.fdopen(c2pread, 'rb', bufsize)
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c.py", line 39, in <module>
    Utils().run_command("ls -lrt")
  File "c.py", line 35, in run_command
    close_fds=True, cwd=cwd, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 740, in __init__
    self.stdout = os.fdopen(c2pread, 'rb', bufsize)
  File "c.py", line 21, in sigchld_handler
    stdout_val = p.communicate()[0]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'communicate'
```

There is no good way to solve this problem with signals that I can think of. But there are other problems with your code, such as the potential for deadlock if the child process `stdout` or `stderr` pipes fill. Instead of signals, you could use a background thread to call `Popen.communicate` and use the `poll` and `wait` methods to see if the process is complete.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import subprocess
import time
import threading

flag = False
class Utils(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.child = None
        self._thread = None

    def run_command(self, cmnd, env=None, cwd=None, timeout=0):
        global flag
        flag = True
        cmnd = cmnd.split()
        self.child = subprocess.Popen(cmnd, stdin=None, bufsize=-1, env=env,
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                             close_fds=True, cwd=cwd, preexec_fn=os.setsid)
        self._thread = threading.Thread(target=self._communicate_thread)
        self._thread.start()
        print "Invoked child process " , self.child.pid
        return self

    def _communicate_thread(self):
        self.out, self.err = self.child.communicate()

    def poll(self):
        return self.child.poll()

    def wait(self):
        rc = self.child.wait()
        if self._thread:
            self._thread.join()
            self._thread = None
        return rc

print "Running command .."
cmd = Utils().run_command("ls -lrt")
while True:
    print 'poll', cmd.poll()
    if cmd.poll() is not None:
        break
    else:
        time.sleep(.1)

print 'done', cmd.wait()
print cmd.out
print cmd.err
```